# Write a bash function/script that takes 2 parameters, filename and increment, and then increments the number of the filename by the increment

Tags: bash

I have a folder with files that have the exact structure, that is file01.txt, file02.txt and so on..
i need to write a function that takes the filename, for example file08.txt, and increment, lets say 4, and then renames file08.txt to file12.txt.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
function inc {
        incrementor=$2
        filename=$(basename -- "$1")
        extention="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        number=$(echo "$filename" | tr -dc '0-9')
        let " number+=incrementor "
        filename=$(echo "$filename" | tr -d '0-9')
        mv $1 "$filename$number.$extention"
        echo "$filename $number $extention"
}
filename=$1
increment=$2
inc $filename $increment
```

Got it!

Comment: Please always use `mv -i` or `mv -n` to prevent accidentally overwriting other files if the names match. For example, if you run this on file1.txt, file2.txt, ... file5.txt, etc. you're likely to overwrite file5.txt with (what was) file1.txt before you have a chance to rename it to file9.txt.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for that information, will watch out for these kinds of mistakes in the future.